# Java EE - @MultipartConfig does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I have a .jsp file which sends out a `multipart/form-data` via form to a servlet and when i pass the request to the servlet (from the action attribute), i try to get `request.getParts()` and i get the `Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided` error. mind you, starting the .jsp file i get the same message even before trying to upload the data by form. so the problem might be of .jsp file. I have used @MultipartConfig on my servlet and it didn't work.

here is my DisplayAlbum.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Photo Album</title>
<head></head>
<jsp:useBean id="photoHandleBean" class="src.PhotoHandleBean"/>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="/RequestServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <input type="text" name="txt">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the RequestServlet class

```
package src;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet(name="RequestServlet" ,urlPatterns="/RequestServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class RequsetServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws ServletException, IOException{

        PhotoAlbum pa = PhotoAlbum.getAlbum(rq.getSession());
        if(rq.getContentType() != null && rq.getContentType().contains("multipart/form-dasta")) {
            System.out.println("osdjfosdj");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream input = null;
            String filename = "";
            for(Part p: rq.getParts()) {
                input = p.getInputStream();
                int c = 0;
                while((c = input.read()) != -1) {
                    baos.write(c);
                }
                filename = p.getSubmittedFileName();
            }
            input.close();
            baos.close();
            System.out.println(baos.toByteArray()+"<<<");
            pa.addPhoto(baos.toByteArray(), filename);

        }

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayAlbum.jsp");
        rd.forward(rq, rs);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws ServletException, IOException{
        doGet(rq, rs);
    }

}
```

and PhotoAlbum class

```
package src;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class PhotoAlbum {
    private List<String> filename = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<byte[]> imageFile = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public static PhotoAlbum getAlbum(HttpSession session) {
        if(session.getAttribute("album") == null) {
            PhotoAlbum pa = new PhotoAlbum();
            session.setAttribute("album", pa);
        }
        return (PhotoAlbum) session.getAttribute("album");
    }

    public List<byte[]> getImages(){
        return this.imageFile;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageFile.size();
    }

    public void addPhoto(byte[] photoByte, String filename) {
        imageFile.add(photoByte);
        this.filename.add(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a typo `getContentType().contains("multipart/form-dasta")` should be `getContentType().contains("multipart/form-data")`

Comment: that was just a typing mistake while i was posting. in the real code this was written correctly. i found the issue and it was with the application server i was using. thank you